# Reversar suma acumulada en MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

quiero solicitar ayuda debido a que tengo una estructura de tabla en MySQL como la que se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo cantidad se acumula la suma por cada día transcurrido independiente para cada ubicación, pero requiero mediante una vista con select obtener el valor diario (la resta entre la cantidad del día anterior y actual registro), el resultado esperado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con el siguiente código pero no logro hacer que cambie recorra todas las ubicaciones:

```
set @CumulativeSum := (select min(d.cantidad) from ventas d where d.ubicacion = 1);

select *, (@CumSum :=@CumulativeSum + d.cantidad) as CumSum, 
    (@CumulativeSum := @CumulativeSum - @CumSum) 
from ventas d 
where d.ubicacion = 1
order by d.ubicacion, d.fecha;
```

El resultado es el esperado pero solo filtrando por una ubicación y necesito todas en la misma salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su atención y ayuda, es para aplicar sobre MySQL 8.0,

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! probaste algo?

Comment: Qué versión de mySQL utilizas?

Comment: Buenos días, la versión es 8.0, gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Gracias, acabo de actualizar la publicación dando un poco de detalle con lo que he probado, en sí funciona pero necesito recorrer todas las ubicaciones para poner en una vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con MySQL 8 aprovecha las funciones de ventana:

```
SELECT v.*
     , cantidad -lead(cantidad) over(PARTITION BY ubicacion       
ORDER BY fecha DESC) cantidad_diaria
  FROM ventas v
```

`lead()` regresa el valor del renglón siguiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba.